# How to use Firebase query in Angular factory?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I'm trying to get the new Firebase queries working in my factory, but I'm stuck. I want to return the value of 'logo' out of my opponents table, based on the opponent name. I can get the example with `console.log` from the Firebase docs running:

```
function OpponentService($firebase) {
    var factory = {};
    var _url = 'https://somefirebaseproject.firebaseio.com/opponents';
    var _ref = new Firebase(_url);

    factory.getLogo = function(opponent) {
        _ref.orderByChild('name').equalTo(opponent).on("child_added", function(snapshot){
            console.log(snapshot.val().logo);
        });
    };

    return factory;
}
```

When I call my factory with `OpponentService.getLogo(opponentName)` in my controller, I get the correct logo id in my console. But how can I return the value instead of sending it to my console? I want to store it in a variable like this: `$scope.opponentLogo = OpponentService.getLogo(opponentName)`. I tried several variations with a return statement like this:

```
factory.getLogo = function(opponent) {
        _ref.orderByChild('name').equalTo(opponent).on("child_added", function(snapshot){
            return snapshot.val().logo;
        });
};
```

But apparently I don't fully understand how factories work in Angular, because I get an `undefined`. Could it be that the value isn't available yet and I should use a promise in someway? Anyone who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're returning the value of logo from the anonymous function inside the Firebase `on()` call, but you're not returning anything from `getLogo()`.

Returning a promise would be a good way to do this. This is how you retrieve the opponent logo with [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/index.html), if there is no guarantee `opponentName` will be unique:

```
// getLogo() returns a promise that you can bind to the UI.
// When loading finishes, the binding will get the opponent's logo value.
factory.getLogo = function (opponentName) {
    var opponentsArray = $firebase(_ref.orderByChild('name').equalTo(opponentName)).$asArray();

    // $loaded() returns a promise, so we can use the then() method to add
    // functionality when the array finishes loading and the promise resolves.
    var r = opponentsArray.$loaded().then(function () {
        // Now return the logo for the first matching opponent
        return opponentsArray[0].logo;
    });

    return r;
};
```

If `opponentName` *is* unique, I would rethink the data structure so that you could use the opponentName as the key for opponents. Then you would be guaranteed to get a single opponent and could fetch it with:

```
var opponent = $firebase(_ref.child(opponentName)).$asObject();
```

If you're not using AngularFire, you can return a promise using Angular's `$q` service. The following should work:

```
factory.getLogo = function(opponent) {
    $q(function (resolve, reject) {
        function successCallback(snapshot) {
            resolve(snapshot.val().logo);
        };

        function cancelCallback(error) {
            reject(error);  // pass along the error object
        };

        _ref.orderByChild('name').equalTo(opponent)
            .on("child_added", successCallback, cancelCallback);
    });
};
```

You can assign the result of `getLogo()` to a scope variable, and bindings will update in the UI when Firebase returns the value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check tonight if this works. I'm already using AngularFire, so this should be easy you say?

Comment: Are you trying to return the logo for a single opponent? Do you need to access or bind to other properties of the opponent in your app?

Comment: Yes in this method I only need to return the logo for a single opponent. But the whole factory contains more methods, like `factory.getAllOpponents`.

Comment: If you get all opponents using Angularfire `$asArray()` method, you already have all opponent data locally and you can search the array for the matching name and logo. You can even use the [Angular's 'filter' filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) to filter by property value in an array.

Comment: That is the way how it works now: I store all opponent data locally and search that array. But now I want to try the new querying methods on this, because I need them anyway later on in my app. I tried to return a promise with Angularfire, but I still can't get it working. How and where should I return the `snapshot.val().logo`? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @Lennert, I updated my answer with an AngularFire example. (Could not test the code, but "it should work". ;)

Comment: thanks I get it working now and I will rethink the data structure :)

Comment: My experience with Firebase is that you will need to rethink the data structure not once but many times during a project. :) The best structure seems to come from how data is retrieved. Think first what you need out of Firebase, and structure data around those needs.

Comment: @NikoNyman - Great answer!  Quick follow up question - what if you were trying to grab multiple datapoints from firebase? The factory gets an array of ids that you use to pull from firebase.  How do you create a promise that the factory returns?  Thanks!