# Creating a promise for accessing multiple datapoints from firebase using angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I have a factory that gets an array of ID's that I use to pull data from firebase.

1 ID pulls 1 piece of data from firebase

I want to create a factory that returns a promise that resolves an array of firebase objects.

Here's an example of a factory that does it for one datapoint (retrieved from the solution of [How to use Firebase query in Angular factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27158562/3527354))

```
// getLogo() returns a promise that you can bind to the UI.
// When loading finishes, the binding will get the opponent's logo value.
factory.getLogo = function (opponentName) {
    var opponentsArray = $firebase(_ref.orderByChild('name').equalTo(opponentName)).$asArray();

    // $loaded() returns a promise, so we can use the then() method to add
    // functionality when the array finishes loading and the promise resolves.
    var r = opponentsArray.$loaded().then(function () {
        // Now return the logo for the first matching opponent
        return opponentsArray[0].logo;
    });

    return r;
};
```

Here's what I've tried -

```
return function(arrIds){
      var obj;
      var arr = [];
      var ctr = 0;
      var defer = $q.defer();

      if (arrIds.constructor == Array){

        for (var i = 0; i < invoiceId.length; i++){

          obj = $firebaseObject(ref.child('invoices').child('company').child(arrIds[i]));

          obj.$loaded().then(function(){

            arr.push(obj);

            if (ctr === arrIds.length){
              ctr++;
              defer.resolve(arr);
              return defer.promise;
            }

          })
        }

      }
};
```

Comment: First thought is, what have you tried and what didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all). I simulated an async request using `$timeout` but the following should give you an idea.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myController', function($scope, myService) {
  myService.getAll([1,2,3,4,5]).then(function(results) {
    $scope.results = results;
  });
});

app.service('myService', function($q, $timeout) {
  this.getAll = function(ids) {
    var promises = [];
    
    ids.forEach(function(id) {
      promises.push(getForId(id));
    });
    
    return $q.all(promises);
  };
  
  function getForId(id) {
    return $timeout(function() {
      return 'Results for ' + id;
    }, Math.random() * 2000);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='myController'>
  <pre>{{ results | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: this is great and I implemented it with no errors! However, the results var is coming back empty!  Basically, the stuff in getForId() is happening after the return $q.all(promises).  Any thoughts?

Comment: `then` of `$q.all` should not happen until all the promises in the promise array resolve. Make sure your `getForId()` equivalent is returning promises.